# Does the mere sight or darshan of the deity in a Vishnu temple wash away all sins?

Tags: vishnu

Does just getting darshan of the deity wash away all sins?

Comment: You can possibly read 'The second chance' by Srila Prabhupada for detailed discussion on the essence of such verses in our scriptures.